# serialize jquery not working for two input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want send 2 variables input whene i do 1 input working but with 2 input not working what is the problem

code html

```
<form method="POST" class="form_add" >

<input type="text" name="comment" class="comment_input" >
<input type="text" name="nump" value="<?php echo trim(htmlspecialchars($row['id_post'])); ?>">                                
</form>
```

code ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '.form_add', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
        method : 'POST',
        data :$(this).serialize() ,
        url : 'traitementCommentPost.php',
        success : function(data)
        {

            $('.fetch_all_comment').prepend(data)  ;        
        }

    });
});
```

page  traitementCommentPost.php for database mysql

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{

if(isset($_POST['comment'],$_POST['nump']) && !empty($_POST['comment']) 
    && !empty($_POST['nump']) )

{



    $comment = (string) trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']));
    $idpost = (int) trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nump']));
    $id_user = (int)trim(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id']));



    $commentL = strlen($comment);


    if($commentL <1 || $commentL > 200) 
    {
        // ajouter plus du détails 


    }
    else 
        {

    if(preg_match("/^([\s*a-zA-Z0-9é\â\ô\î\'\û\-\+\.\=\/\?\!\:\;\[\]\,\_\(\)\'\%\ç\è\ê\#\Ω\<\>\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+\s*)+$/u",$comment)) 
            {


                    $stmt=$connect->prepare('INSERT INTO
                                                    comment_post(id_post,
                                                    id_user,comment,date_comment)
                                                         VALUES(:a,:b,:c,NOW())');
                    $stmt->bindValue(':a',$idpost,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':b',$id_user,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':c',$comment,PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    $stmt->execute();



            }  // preg match
        }  // else 

}
}
```

i want send 2 variables input whene i do 1 input working but with 2 input not working what is the problem

Comment: What's in traitementCommentPost.php?

Comment: code edited (page insert to database)

Comment: "2 input not working" what exactly means by this. What is the expected  behavior and what is happening, at which line of code you are not receiving input value?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend against using `empty()` to check if strings are empty, as [certain strings are considered empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues), even with non-whitespace characters.

Also, I'm not sure if you're showing the entire `traitementCommentPost.php`, but if you are, using `session_start()` at the beginning is good practice if you are using `SESSION` variables.

Could you also describe more specifically the error you are getting? Are you missing the variables in your PHP script, or are you missing records in the table?